# wxpython statictext abnormal display

Tags: wxpython

This is my code,  and I've defined a frame, its execution is confusing.

```
import wx
class GoToClass(wx.Frame):
   
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(GoToClass, self).__init__(parent, title=title, 
            size=(500, 350))
             
        self.InitUI()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()     
         
    def InitUI(self):
     
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
 
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
 
        hbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        st1 = wx.StaticText(panel, wx.ID_ANY, u"Class Name")
        hbox1.Add(st1, flag=wx.RIGHT|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, border=8)

        tc = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
        hbox1.Add(tc, proportion=1)
        vbox.Add(hbox1, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, border=10)

        panel.SetSizer(vbox)

def run():
    app = wx.App()
    GoToClass(None, title='')
    app.MainLoop()

run()
```

Sometimes it works well, but sometimes it turns out like this.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxOu9.png)

Comment: You don't mention what environment you are running this in but on first glance, this does appear confusing. It definitely should `not` be inconsistent.

Comment: oh,yeah.The program runs on wxpython4.1.0, python3.6.3, Win10.I looked at the documentation, but I couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: I was wondering about an IDE. I usually recommend running it from the command line to see if it is still an issue. If it isn't, the problem lies in the environment/IDE.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.i try to run it from the powershell and cmd, but the result is the same.

Comment: I also noticed that after the program runs, it display get right if i firstly resize the height of windows to 0 and then resize the window to normal size.

Comment: Try it without `sizers` by using `pos=(xx,yy)` values for the widgets. The only other thing that springs to mind, as a distant hope, would be to test it using a different desktop `theme` (if those exist in Win10)